# Why is VisualStudio deploying libraries on each launch again?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, windows-mobile

Right now I'm developing a Windows Mobile 6.0 application. When I want to test the user interface, I deploy the application from Visual Studio 2008 to the emulator or a physical device. Unfortunately the deployment is really slow, because the IDE is installing some dependencies on each launch again.

[image: Bla]

Is there a way to avoid this somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out, this is happening, because the referenced version of `System.Data.SqlServerCe` is different to the version on the device or in the emulator, which came with the Compact Framework. To solve this problem is just removed and added again the reference to the `System.Data.SqlServerCe` library.

I've found this solution here:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/68e8d920-edd5-4aab-aa4f-ba0bfcf42d26/vs2008-how-to-stop-sqlce-cab-from-deploying-on-every-debug-session